# "Help me debug" vs "Help me debugging" vs "Help me in debugging"

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, verbs

I asked a question on SO, and I wrote

> Yesterday I asked a question so that you could *help me debug* a program...

Then I felt like the italic part isn't actually correct English, and I thought that the correct expression would be

Help me debugging or help me in debugging a program

Which of the three are correct? If more than one, which one sounds more familiar? What's the general case rule when we have "help" followed by another verb (like in my case above)?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "... that you could help me debug a program..."

Comment: It is OK. In English you can write either help + verb or help + to + verb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence

> Yesterday I asked a question so that you could **help me debug** a program...

is correct and understandable, you might also use

> Yesterday I asked a question so that you could **help me** ***in*** **debugging** a program...
>   Yesterday I asked a question so that you could **help me** ***with*** **debugging** a program...
>   Yesterday I asked a question so that you could **help me** ***to*** **debug** a program...

The choice is stylistic, however **with** may be more common
since you are asking for help **with** *something*.